# Custom Events not received in Google Anallytics Dashboard

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to send a custom event to my GA. However, GA does not show any data in the dashboard.

Here's my UPDATED code:-- (As suggested by @Дмитро Булах)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXX-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXX-1');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button-cta').click(function() {

          alert(111)
          gtag('event', 'click', {
            'event_category': 'Deal click',
            'event_label': 'URL1',
            'value': '1'
          });
          alert(111)
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
<button id="button-cta">1111</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I view my data in `Reports -> RealTime -> Events`. It shows nothing.

**PS: I'm developing this locally, and have opened a HTML file in the browser.**

Comment: Check the real-time reports in google analytics.   are you seeing the data there?

Answer (score 0):

since you're using **gtag.js** snippet you need to use `gtag(...)` object to track events, like

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

`ga(...)` works with older analytics snippet, **analytics.js**
More on event tracing with `gtag(...)` [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events)

Comment: Done. Please see my updated code. How much time does it take to reflect on GA?

Comment: Does opening a file on a browser effects the functioning of GA?

Comment: looks like gtag doesn't work properly with local files at file:// try serve your page  at localhost

Answer (score 0):

The GTAG event method is the right way to go as per the previous answer by @Дмитро Булах . If you are testing locally on a HTML I don't think the event will fire to Google Analytics, I would suggest implementing and testing on a staging environment if possible and then testing the event is firing either using the Event Tracking tracker plugin or Real Time report in Google Analytics.